# Ubuntu - Is it normal that my apache webroot is in html directory

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php

I have installed PHP, MySQL, and Apache in my machine by following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP) tutorial. I created one file info.php to test if php is working on my apache server, but I go message file not found.
Then, I tried to place info.php file inside html directory, it worked fine. Is it possible to change it to /var/www not in /var/www/html?

Please help. I am new to linux.

Comment: That usually happens on the later versions of Ubuntu (14.04). It's perfectly fine as long as your DocumentRoot points there. By the way, you can change it if you like

Comment: check out the index.html page because it's not just an "it works!" page, it actually explains some of the differences. Also, take a look at the file /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz you will need to unzip it but it contains allot of info on how to do what you are talking about. Finally, run the command `man apache2` in an open terminal to read the manual pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can do  something like this

```
 #open suphp.conf file 
 gksu "gedit /etc/suphp/suphp.conf
 #or like this
 sudo nano /etc/suphp/suphp.conf
 #change the document root folder 
 docroot=/var/www/  
 #to
 docroot=/home/user/public_html/
 #restart apache
 sudo service apache2 restart  
 #or like this
 sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 #test your new location
 echo "<?php echo 'whoim = '.exec('/usr/bin/whoami');?>" | tee /home/user/public_html/whomi.php
```

Now open your browser and navigate to **localhost/whomi.php** and you should see your ID. More detailed documentation can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)